# How to avoid / remove blank space in .row

Tags: javascript, css, prestashop

It is my first time using Prestashop, I have a strange problem where items do not flow in the correct order. There some white space in the second/third rows usually.

Please have a look on the website for example:
https://lascelta.eu/13-vitello

Each product is a `div` with the `class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"` in the `.row div, however`, this problem still appears.

[image: Empty space]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First 2 div height are 413px.
The third is only 411px.
So you need to `clear: both;` each 3 items on *md* size, each 2 on *sm* :

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .item:nth-child(3n + 1) {
        clear: both;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.99px) {
    .item:nth-child(2n + 1) {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not work unfortunately, I tried using your code.

Comment: How did you try this CSS ?  
When I append the code  with the Browser DevTools to https://lascelta.eu/themes/organic2/assets/cache/theme-9a3d6f54.css , it look nice.

Comment: Yeah, it works offline at the Browser DevTools, but it does not work when I try it online (FTP).

Comment: It seems you have a cache system minifying CSS.  
You probably need to clear/refresh this cache.  
PS: i d'ont know *Prestashop*, can't help on this point.

Comment: It worked bro, thanks a lot. I had to first clear the cache at the website and start fresh and clean!

Comment: You're right, I did the same as you said in your last comment, you helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have this style on the `col-md-4` class. Just remove it and it should work fine.

```
.col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}
```